# How do I check for XHR in node

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

Ive seen another question answered about checking for ajax requests in express by looking in

```
    req.xhr
```

however this comes through as false when angular is requesting a template, surely this is ajax??

Please help!

Comment: Some helper libraries will set `X-Requested-With`, but IMHO you shouldn't rely on it. Browsers do not automatically send a particular identifier with requests sent via XHR, it's an application-level thing.

Answer (score 0):

`req.xhr` is used to tell whether the request is ordinary browser request or it's an Ajax request. Most frameworks set the `X-Requested-With` header to `XMLHttpRequest`, You can check this in Express :

```
app.get('/path', function(req, res) {
  var is_ajax = req.xhr;    // this tells whether the request is ajax (true) or not (false)
  ...
});
```

Comment: Maybe I wasnt clear, my thinking is that this should be true when angular gets a template. However its showing as false.

Comment: `MOST` frameworks set the X-Requested-With header to XMLHttpRequest. But you can't rely on it.